# TypeError: can't concat str to bytes - Python + pycryptodome

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, pycryptodome

I'm receiving a TypeError when trying to encrypt + decrypt a file using pycryptodome. I've looked around but can't find much relevant to pycryptodome regarding this. The error is:
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS8yZ.png)

The code I'm using is:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
import binascii



print("Now executing RSA")
# generate the RSA keys and print them on the console (as hex numbers and in the PKCS#8 PEM ASN.1 format)

keyPair = RSA.generate(3072)

pubKey = keyPair.publickey()
print(f"Public key:  (n={hex(pubKey.n)}, e={hex(pubKey.e)})")
pubKeyPEM = pubKey.exportKey()
print(pubKeyPEM.decode('ascii'))

print(f"Private key: (n={hex(pubKey.n)}, d={hex(keyPair.d)})")
privKeyPEM = keyPair.exportKey()
print(privKeyPEM.decode('ascii'))

# encrypt the message using RSA-OAEP encryption scheme (RSA with PKCS#1 OAEP padding) with the RSA public key
# msg = b'A message for encryption'
f = open("plaintext.txt", "r")
f = f.read()
encryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(pubKey)
encrypted = encryptor.encrypt(f)
print("Encrypted:", binascii.hexlify(encrypted))

# decrypt the message using RSA-OAEP with the RSA Private key

decryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(keyPair)
decrypted = decryptor.decrypt(encrypted)
print('Decrypted:', decrypted)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert plaintext into bytes or read file as binary data. add `b` to read file as binary data.

```
f = open("plaintext.txt", "rb")
```

A side note You should consider closing the file after finishing using it

```
file = open("plaintext.txt", "rb")
f = file.read()
encryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(pubKey)
encrypted = encryptor.encrypt(f)
print("Encrypted:", binascii.hexlify(encrypted))
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both data types are equal. You can try converting the text file to bytes so the data types are equal, and hence can be concatenated.